# Reading function from txt file in C?

Tags: c

I have numerical integration program, and I want to read the function from text file and calculate the function with postfix algorithm. My problem is,how can I read `sin`,`log` etc. from file and put them into array.For numbers I maybe use the `strtol()` function like this :

```
int main(){
    int i;
    char *str = "ab234 56 cid*(s349*(20kd", *p = str;
    while (*p) { 
        if (isdigit(*p)) { 
            long val = strtol(p, &p, 10); 
            printf("%ld\n", val);
        } else { 
            p++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't parse your example string. Should the function be given in infix format (`2*sin(x*pi)`) or in postfix (`x pi sin 2 mult`)?

Comment: The example string is just for reading numbers. The function should be given in postfix format.

Comment: Do you write your code in notepad?? use some IDE!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can't just magically go from the string `sin` to calculating the sine function. You have to write code to do that.

I'd recommend splitting the input into tokens (perhaps just using `strtok()` in a loop), then inspecting each token.

For numbers, push the numbers onto your stack (I assume you want a stack since you mention the functions/operators being postfix).

For strings (names of functions), look them up in a hardcoded table or `if`-series and do the evaluation.

Something like:

```
char **tokens = ... // NULL-terminated list of input tokens
int i = 0;
while(tokens[i] != NULL)
{
  if(isdigit(tokens[i][0]))
  {
    stack_push(strtol(token, NULL, 10));
  }
  else if(strcmp(tokens[i], "sin") == 0)
  {
    stack_push(sin(stack_pop()));
  }
  else if ...
}
```

Note that this is very rough, only intended to give an outline of how this can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions. One:

> how can I read sin,log etc. from file

The other:

> how can I ... put them into array

---

First question: reading from file. Use `strtok` to separate a line of text into "words". Use `strcmp` to examine the function name.

```
int main(){
    char str[] = "2 3 +";
    char *p;
    for (p = strtok(str, " "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        if (isdigit(*p)) { // it's a number
            long val = strtol(p, &p, 10); 
            printf("%ld\n", val);
        } else { // it's a name of a function
            if (strcmp(p, "+") == 0)
                puts("Add");
            else if (strcmp(p, "-") == 0)
                puts("Subtract");
            else if (strcmp(p, "sin") == 0)
                puts("Sine");
            else if (strcmp(p, "log") == 0)
                puts("Logarithm");
            else if ...
            ...
            else
                fputs("Error!", stderr);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Second question: adding to an array. I recommend using a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union):

```
enum type {CONSTANT, UNARY_FUNCTION, BINARY_FUNCTION, X};

struct operation
{
    enum type type;
    union {
        double val;
        double (*func1)(double); // a pointer to a function with 1 argument
        double (*func2)(double, double); // a pointer to a function with 2 arguments
    };
};
```

Here, there are 4 possible types for an "operation" - it can be a number, an unary function (like `sin`), a binary function (like `+`) or an independent variable `x`.

To convert a token `p` to an `operation`:

```
char *p;
struct operation o;
...
if (isdigit(*p)) { // it's a number
    o.type = CONSTANT;
    o.val = strtol(p, &p, 10); 
} else { // it's a name of a function or "x"
    if (strcmp(p, "x") == 0)
    {
        o.type = X;
    }
    else if (strcmp(p, "+") == 0)
    {
        o.type = BINARY_FUNCTION;
        o.func2 = plus;
    }
    else if (strcmp(p, "sin") == 0)
    {
        o.type = UNARY_FUNCTION;
        o.func1 = sin;
    }
    else if (strcmp(p, "log") == 0)
    {
        o.type = UNARY_FUNCTION;
        o.func1 = log;
    }
    ...
}
```

Here the function `plus` adds two numbers. Standard library doesn't have it (unlike `sin`, which it has), so I have to define it by myself:

```
double plus(double x, double y) {return x + y;}
```

Finally, if you have an array of `operation` objects:

```
struct operation my_array[1000];
```

you can add objects to the array:

```
struct operation my_array[1000];
size_t my_array_size = 0;

for (...)
{
    ... // parse input file
    struct operation o;
    ... // parse individual token and convert it to an "operation"
    my_array[my_array_size++] = o; // add to the array
}
```

---

The main part of the program is using the array to calculate the value of the encoded function for any value of `x`. Now that you have your function encoded as an array of operations, the calculation itself will be easy. Just make a temporary stack of values, and apply each operation.

Comment: What i should do with 'x' ?  example : sin(x) 5 *

Comment: Updated my answer. BTW you might want to encode your function in postfix manner, like `x sin 5 *` - code is easier that way